# "The address entered appears to be invalid. Please correct your address and resubmit." I am getting error in itune

Tags: app-store-connect, subscriptions, auto-renewable

I am getting following error while updating the address in iTunes sign agreement page.

```
The address entered appears to be invalid. Please correct your address and resubmit.
```

Can anyone help me on how to resolve this error?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about managing a business relationship, communicating between the question OP and a third party, and/or dealing with a legal issue. In other words, it's not about programming as defined in the [help/on-topic]. You might be able to get help from the Customer Service for the company you are interfacing with.

Comment: I solved this by submitting the request information three times.

Comment: Also make sure you are logged in as the **Account Holder**

Comment: @SurentharPitchai solution works. This is ridiculous..

Comment: I solved submitting three times the same data

Comment: Worked clicking three times than refreshing the page. Congrats Apple!

Comment: LOL what about logic why Apple  doing that

Comment: Didn't work for me as of August 2021. This worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68886850/848015

Answer (score 28):

Issue resolved. Apple developer panel accepts "#" as one of the characters in first line of address.

Exampe :

```
# 111 My Address
Street Name
City Name
```

Answer (score 5):

Deleting a whitespace at the end of the address section solved the issue for me.

Comment: Explain your answer

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had N/A in the region field. Changing that to the proper region worked.

Comment: I changed the N/A to my city name without changing anything else and clicked submit like 5 times for it to work. This is crazy