# The address entered appears to be invalid. Please correct your address and resubmit

Tags: app-store-connect, apple-developer

I am new to iOS development. I have a Apple ID. In that I am getting following error while updating the address in iTunes connect agreements, tax, and banking page.

**I have used address like this**

[image]

**here I have display the screen shot of my error**

[image]

how to rectify this error.

Comment: Fill the address properly.

Comment: I have filled it properly like this [ No.12 Step Colony Dharga ] then also it gets same error.

Comment: have u filled all the fields?

Comment: In Address line 1 I have filled like this [ No.12 Step Colony Dharga ]. In address line 2 and address line 3 I didn't fill any thing. I have filled everything for other fields.

Comment: Do it like these -> `address1 : H.No12` ..  `address2 : ABC Street` .. `address3 : Alpha Colony`. Split your addres like this and fill all fields

Comment: I have tried like that also. but I am getting same error.

Comment: I'm getting the same error today, I place the correct data... then I click in Save and the model is opened again with the same error message

Comment: Try to click add/save button 3-4 time and it will work, worked for me.!

Answer (score 81):

You can try this solution found on [AppDeveloper](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/112590)

> Just found a solution. Try clicking the add/save/submit button 3 times.

It worked for me.

Comment: OMG, this is crazy

Comment: This was apple's validations

Comment: I tried that, but got either `We are currently unable to process your request. Please try again later.` or `Cannot Parse xml returned by WebMethods`

Comment: Wow, this has been a problem for a very long time than. Fixed it for me too, thanks for this answer ;D

Comment: Haha! This solved my issue today. Seems like the bug has been around for a long time. Crazy indeed.

Comment: what else do you expect from Apple.

Comment: Damn what did just happen? +1

Comment: Yup, this was the solution for me too, over a year later. Good job, Apple. 

Comment: apple is joking

Comment: Hahaha. This solution still works. 1st of July 2020.

Comment: It's horrible. I also tap 15/20 second interval. It was not working. However, then I tried simultaneously three times. it's working. But Shame

Comment: worked for me clicking as desperate, thanks and WTF!

Comment: It is 2021 and it is still a thing. Works.

Comment: OMG. It is valid still 2021/01/07. Apple shows off their software skill here.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I have a solution below as of August 2021

Comment: LOL, this helped me add the address to the banking info. Thank you!

Comment: This answer is now wrong. You now have to click 4 times. I'm not even joking... LOL

Comment: I had to click 4 times! WT eFF

Answer (score 3):

Clicking multiple times didn't work for me as of August 23, 2021.

What worked was sniffing the **XHR** traffic in chrome, copied the **CURL Request**, modified the **PUT** body request **JSON** property under `accountHolderAddress` > `sameAddressRetryCount: 0`, and changed the value to `5` pasted in the terminal and voila! Problem solved!

Looks like you have to tell Apple you've tried so much already until they accept your request.

- If you have **Postman**, you can even import the **CURL** as **Raw Text**, and edit the request more conveniently

Comment: How to change value accountHolderAddress > sameAddressRetryCount: from 0 to 5

Answer (score 0):

When I inspect the XHR request, I see "Insufficient Privileges" as the reason it fails.  I am an "Admin" but not account owner, so that might be the problem.

If only it said that instead of just "The address entered appears to be invalid. Please correct your address and resubmit." that would have saved me some time!

Answer (score 0):

I had to click 4 times to make the agreement pop up. Just keep on clicking until it 'unlocks' haha!